# What is (s/g)etFreezesText in TextView?

Tags: android, textview

As of recently (probably as a new SDK feature), when I try to pull text from a `Textview`, I first get the method `getFreezesText()`, instead of `getText()`.

I looked at the definition of this method and it says

```
**android:freezesText**

If set, the text view will include its current complete text inside of its frozen icicle in addition to meta-data such as the current cursor position. By default this is disabled; it can be useful when the contents of a text view is not stored in a persistent place such as a content provider.
Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".
This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol freezesText.

Related Methods
setFreezesText(boolean)
```

This tells nothing to me.

When we are supposed to use these methods (if ever at all)? Are they new or I've just noticed them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to force your `TextView` (or `EditText` etc. for that matter) to save its state you must add [`freezesText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3afreezesText) attribute:

```
<TextView 
     ... 
     android:freezesText="true" />
```

From documentation on [`freezesText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3afreezesText) :

> If set, the text view will include its current complete text inside of its frozen icicle in addition to meta-data such as the current cursor position. By default this is disabled; it can be useful when the contents of a text view is not stored in a persistent place such as a content provider

The attribute and method have existed since API 1, so I'll say you just noticed it.

Comment: And how does the output look like? Is it only visible text (in case text length is larger then TextView width)?

Comment: The documentation says `current complete text`. I haven't used it personally though.

Answer (score 2):

`android:freezesText="true"` will **freeze** your last completed text.

> What is the last completed Text?

Suppose you are showing a `textView` which is changing after every 2 seconds everything is okay until you rotate the screen and if you rotate the screen the text inside textView will not be visible, here `freezesText` comes, it will freeze the last showed text (last completed Text).